# Source from a string

Tags: tcl

How do I source from a string and not from a file

This is how we usually source a file

```
// somename.tcl
proc someName {} {
    # The {} above means a list of zero formal arguments
    puts "Hello from inside someName"
}
```

I can source this from any other tcl file in the following way

```
//main.tcl
source "somename.tcl"

//call someName 
someName
```

Instead of the above, i would like to read contents of somename.tcl into a string and source the string. I want the contents of the string to be sourced in the same process context.

Like below

```
//main.tcl 
set filename "somename.tcl" 
set f [open $filename] 
set content [read $f]

# I want to source the content here
#How do i do it?
```

Comment: [eval](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

The `source` command does something *very much* like this internally:

```
# Reading phase
set f [open $filename]
try {
    fconfigure $f -encoding $encoding -eofchar "\032"
    set contents [read $f]
} finally {
    close $f
}

# Evaluation phase
set oldScript [info script]
try {
    info script $filename
    eval $contents
} finally {
    info script $oldScript
}
```

where `$encoding` defaults to what `[encoding system]` reports. Except it does it in C and has some extra complication for simple argument parsing, and has somewhat different error handling in regard to stack traces.

In the simple case, you can convert that down to:

```
set f [open $filename]
set contents [read $f]
close $f
eval $contents
```

The `eval` command is the key here: it **eval**uates a Tcl script in a string. It's not very often used in modern Tcl, but for something like this it is the command of choice.

---

If you put the code inside a procedure, you need to change the `eval` for `uplevel 1` to have the correct semantics; `source` does *not* change the stack frame for you:

```
proc simpleSource {filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    set contents [read $f]
    close $f

    uplevel 1 $contents
}
```